# Can not find where I am overwriting styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem when I am trying to include [jQuery Notebook plugin](https://github.com/raphaelcruzeiro/jquery-notebook) into my twitter bootstrap page. The problem is that CSS of the plugin became messed up. For example on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/4FwDQ/) if you will select text, you see that controls are not on the right places.

But if you will [remove bootstrap CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/4FwDQ/2/) - everything is ok.

Looking at jQuery notebook css, I can see that all of the classes use

```
.jquery-notebook ....{

}
```

So it is highly unlikely that they overwrite any of twitter's styles. How can I fix the styles here?

If out of a sudden in 5 years the jsfiddle will disappear, you can still find the code here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.notebook.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">

<div class="my-editor">
    Here is my text    
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-editor').notebook();
});
</script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.notebook.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why does someone with 8K rep put their whole question in multiple fiddles?  When those are no longer valid, your question will make zero sense.

Comment: @JeremyMiller Can not understand what exactly do you mean. Why the fiddles would not be valid? Also what's wrong with 8k rep, does it makes a difference?

Comment: 5 years from now when the links don't work and SO is still around, your question will be worthless.  AFAIK, it is recommended to post the code and then link to a fiddle or other such silly site so that others can check it out for rapid debugging... then your question and the answers stand the test of time.

Comment: @JeremyMiller sorry to annoy you with my fiddles here, but I can see fiddles here which are more than a year old. And everything is ok with it. Also in five years, most probably no one would care about using bootstrap 3.0 with jquerynotebook. So I do not see your point. Also the whole code is like 5 lines of code, and without both libraries it is useless. But if you really think that this is a correct way, it is not hard for me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap adds a margin top and bottom to the elements with class names `h1` and `h2`. Try making the margins zero for these two elements in your css.

```
.h1,.h2{
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is Bootstrap override **ul** **margin property**. so you can use bootstrap with jquery notebook plugin you just change small modification to solve this problem,

#### jquery.notebook.css

**Old style** (line number **74**)

```
.jquery-notebook.bubble ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
```

}

**new style**

```
.jquery-notebook.bubble ul {
     padding: 0;
     margin: -20px 0;      // Add top margin -20px
     list-style: none;
}
```